# Unknown lifecycle phase while running mvn test -Dcucumber.filter.tags="@tag1"

Tags: exception, testing, automation, build, cucumber

I am trying to run a scenario tag using IntelliJ terminal on Windows but its throwing error:

> [ERROR] Unknown lifecycle phase ".filter.tags=@tag1". You must specify a valid lifecycle phase or a goal in the format : or <plugin
> -group-id>:[:]:. Available lifecycle phases are: pre-clean, clean, post-clean, validate, initialize, generate-
> sources, process-sources, generate-resources, process-resources, compile, process-classes, generate-test-sources, process-test-sources, generate-test-re
> sources, process-test-resources, test-compile, process-test-classes, test, prepare-package, package, pre-integration-test, integration-test, post-integr
> ation-test, verify, install, deploy, pre-site, site, post-site, site-deploy. -> [Help 1]
> [ERROR]
> [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
> [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
> [ERROR]
> [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
> [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/LifecyclePhaseNotFoundException

I am trying to run a scenario tag using IntelliJ terminal on Windows. It supposed to run the Chrome browser and run the test.

Comment: I am using <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
            <version>7.11.2</version>
            <!--            <scope>test</scope>-->
        </dependency>

Comment: Sounds like you are using Powershell. Try `-D"cucumber.filter.tags=@tag1"` instead.